# Jenkins not passing a buildInfo property file to gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

This morning all of our Jenkins builds have failed during the `artifactoryPublish` task with the message:

```
Execution failed for task ':artifactoryPublish'.
> Context URL cannot be empty
```

This is happening for any project I rebuild, even ones that haven't changed in months.

When I compare the console log between a successful and a failed build, one item that pops out is a line like this in the successful builds:

```
[buildinfo] Properties file found at '/tmp/buildInfo4135847729346651998.properties'
```

that is not present for the failed builds. My /tmp directory **does** contain buildInfo*.properties files for the failed builds, but from the console output it looks like the file is not passed to Gradle. The property files contain a `contextUrl` property, which leads me to believe the file missing from my builds is the problem.

Can anyone offer some enlightenment on what could have changed in my configuration or environment to cause this?

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same behaviour implementing our new build system and haven't been able to figure out the cause.  Any update would be appreciated.

Comment: I had to move onto something else in the short term, but plan to get back to this soon. My installation is a couple minor versions behind, so first thing I'll do is make sure it and the plugins are up to date. I'm not sure what that will do, though, because as far as I can tell none of that changed between working and not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after wrestling with what seems like the same issue for some time I found that disabling the Gradle daemon (using --no-daemon) resolved the problem for me.

I also created an issue on the plugins JIRA system to get to the bottom of whether disabling the daemon should be necessary and will update this answer when i get a reply.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @PinkyNoBrain. I'll try that when I'm back in the office. Did you have to turn off the daemon for each job, or is their a central location that works for all Gradle builds?

Comment: I realized I could set `org.gradle.daemon = false` in $HOME/.grade/gradle.properties. What's really strange, though, is I decided to rebuild my projects before turning off the daemon, since I hadn't built them in a few days. This time, they all built successfully, no file changes and no apparent config changes on my part.

Comment: @Jeff French Yes, that actually makes sense.  After a few days of no builds your Gradle daemon will have expired.  When it is started again for the new builds it will be given the properties for this new build and so they succeed.  However, once running, it does not get passed updated properties for subsequent builds, so they fail.  That's what I've deduced from the behaviour on my build server anyway.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down, @PinkyNoBrain!